# QT Custom tree view

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, treeview

I have a data representation as follow:

---

- --+ Parent(0:0)

  - ----+Child1(1:1)
  - - ----+Child11 (2:2)
  - ----+Childn(1:n)

---

I am using a QT treeview and a custom model and am trying to display it.
My requirement is that Parent needs to be in a different column as compared to child.

If parent col:row are 0:0.
Child col:row should be 1:1.
Also further the child's child can have col:row as 2:2

As far as I have read the Qt forums there is no easy way to do this. It says that I would have to implement my custom view based on the the Qt treeview.
Is this the only way? Is there an example of how to implement custom tree like views for reference?
I am using Qt 4.7 on Linux(Ubuntu 12)
Any Help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a half answer, so I'm posting as a comment. Here is a good example of how to do your own tree model. I recommend copoying it wholesale and then reshape it in place to meet your needs.  http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/itemviews-simpletreemodel.html

Comment: @EricJohnson: I believe his problem is with the default QTreeview display behaviour for a typical Tree Model, not the model itself since he already has a custom model implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you can modify the tree view display behaviour without sub-classing QTreeView. An alternative would be to implement a QAbstractProxyModel to map your custom model to the the new proxy model, map each index in the custom model to a different column in the proxy model based on its tree level. I would think the latter method is easier since you are already familiar with implementing a custom model rather than QTreeView.

Have a look at the documentation here: 
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractproxymodel.html

Comment: Yes that is the right approach. I found something similar and useful posted recently on Qt-Apps. here is the Link http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php/QAIV?content=157705, just in case anyone needs for future use. Thanks @ksming